# Draw invisible triangle openGL ES 2.0 without using shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to draw Invisible triangle in OpenGL ES 3.0. I thought making the Alpha channel Zero will do it.
Here is how I am passing my triangle vertices:

In my constructor I am using intialising my Triangle vertices:

```
final float[] triangle2VerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, 
            // R, G, B, A
            -0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,      // Alpha is zero

            0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 
            0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,      // Alpha is zero

            0.0f, 0.559016994f, 0.0f, 
            1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};     // Alpha is zero
```

Extra Information:

In onSurfaceCreated:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
// ... Creating and attaching shaders, creating veiw matrix using Lookat
```

In onDrawFrame:

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
// ... performaing simple rotation and passing MVP to shaders
```

In Shaders:

final String vertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"

```
      + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     
      + "attribute vec4 a_Color;        \n"                   

      + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     

      + "void main()                    \n"     
      + "{                              \n"
      + "   v_Color = a_Color;          \n"      

      + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"     
      + "               * a_Position;   \n"                                                                          
      + "}                              \n";        
    final String fragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;       \n"     

      + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"               
      + "void main()                    \n"     
      + "{                              \n"
      + "   gl_FragColor = v_Color;     \n"               
      + "}
```

I am able to change color of the triangle with playing R G B values.
BUT when A(Alpha) is set to 1.0f or 0.0f Does not produce any change in transperancy/invisiblity?
Can anyone tell me where I am goin wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the triangle to be completely invisible, simply don't render it. This is the best approach for performance, and with a little extra logic, should be easy to accomplish.

If you want some transparency, i.e. not completely invisible, then be sure to enable **blending**. (Plenty of information online about how to do blending. Too much to explain in a post.)

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

after rendering your transparent objects,

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: 1) I want to perform some Occlusion querry for this invisible triangle. That is why I need to draw invisible.
2) But my doubt remains same, by changing Alpha why dont i get any change in the output drawing?

Comment: Well, in order for the alpha channel to take effect, blending needs to be enabled.

Comment: GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE);     The blend func can change to fit your specific needs, but since its completely invisible, the end result will be the same.